# how do you send saved template in mandrill?

Tags: mandrill

So I'm looking at the Mandrill documentation, and I'm a little confused.

All the examples for sending a templated email include the content of the template in the call.  I thought the point of saving templates was so that you could save the template at mandrill.com (which I've done) and just call the template, supplying the replacement variables.  Can you just leave the content fields blank when calling send-template?

Thanks,
kevin

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can pass the `template_content` parameter as an empty array if you don't want to replace certain regions in your template. In general, it allows you to use the same template/skeleton for different types of emails, if desired.

Comment: Got it.  I think that might be a really useful thing to mention in the API docs.